# how to insert multiple adsense units inside blogger post

Tags: blogger, adsense, posts

I bought a blogger template which has the option to add One adsense unit in the middle of each blogger post, and I want to add multiple units in long posts and to decide after how many paragraphs that ads appear after, this is the script of the ads but it is also included in the Layout as shown in the image.
How can I make it possible to add more than one unit inside long posts.

I tried to modify the code as follows, but it didn't work

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
var firstImg = document.querySelector('.amp-content img');firstImg.style.display='none';
function insertAfter2(addition2,target2) {var parent = target.parentNode;if (parent.lastChild == target) {parent.appendChild(addition); } else {parent.insertBefore(addition,target.nextSibling);}}
var adscont = document.getElementById("adsCent");var target = document.getElementById("adsCenter");
var bungkus3 = target.getElementsByTagName("br");if (bungkus3.length > 0){insertAfter(adscont,bungkus3[2]);}
var bungkus = target.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");if (bungkus.length > 0){insertAfter(adscont,bungkus[0]);}
var bungkus2 = target.getElementsByTagName("h2");if (bungkus2.length > 0){insertAfter(adscont,bungkus2[2]);}
    //]]></script>

<div class='mg-ads' id='adsCent'><div class='a3lan-Center'/>
<script>//<![CDATA[
var firstImg = document.querySelector('.amp-content img');firstImg.style.display='none';
function insertAfter(addition,target) {var parent = target.parentNode;if (parent.lastChild == target) {parent.appendChild(addition); } else {parent.insertBefore(addition,target.nextSibling);}}
var adscont = document.getElementById("adsCent");var target = document.getElementById("adsCenter");
var bungkus3 = target.getElementsByTagName("br");if (bungkus3.length > 0){insertAfter(adscont,bungkus3[2]);}
var bungkus = target.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");if (bungkus.length > 0){insertAfter(adscont,bungkus[0]);}
var bungkus2 = target.getElementsByTagName("h2");if (bungkus2.length > 0){insertAfter(adscont,bungkus2[0]);}
    //]]></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there any idea?